# Inaccurate revision information

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, revisions-list

[Why python does not allow hyphens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064329/why-python-does-not-allow-hyphens)

I modified this question's tags to correct "pyhon" to "python".  However, in the revision history, it shows that I changed the title.  There is no indication in the revision history that the tag was changed.

I simply clicked on "edit" on the question page, scrolled straight down to the tags, changed the tag, and clicked Save Edits, without modifying the title field.

Comment: Maybe you can test if a trailing backtick in a title is somehow removed by either your browser or the server? (The tag maybe having been changed by the author within the 5-minute window, while you were trying to do the same?)

Answer (score 3):

Er... what? According to revision history it was *always* tagged [python].

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2064329/list

ah, I see -- as noted in the comments, the original author edited it within the 5 minute grace period after posting. Edits in the 5 minute grace period do not count as "official" edits.

Comment: Maybe unless the author changed it within 5 minutes after posting, while Jeff (not you) was trying the same? 1st revision 13:27:44, Jeff's 13:31:38, another from the author at 13:32:51.

Comment: Ahh, didn't realize there was a 5 minute grace period.  That would explain the disappearing backtick too.